# Obtener datos de formulario Angular 17

Tags: angular, formularios

estoy empezando a aprender **Angular 17** pero me pregunto como puedo **obtener** los datos de un formulario cuando se le hace el  **sumbit**, ya intenté usando **Object.fromEntries** junto **FormData** pero no funciona, y los ejemplos en internet son con versiones anteriores. Me pueden ayudar, porfa? Gracias

Sólo necesitaría un ejemplo de como recibir los datos de un input, qué se necesita para obtenerlo, si hay que usar algún modulo o algo parecido.

Comment: tienes que agregar el código que estas probando

Comment: Estas usando TemplateForms o Reactive Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Tenes muchas maneras de obtener los datos de un formulario usando Angular, lo que más se usa es el modulo que otorga Angular de formularios reactivos (ReactiveFormsModule), podes buscar ejemplos de como usarlo, es algo básico en Angular.

igualmente te dejo el ejemplo que da la documentación de Angular:

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms